# Listen for when react hydrates (outside of react)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering

If I have a server-side rendered web app (e.g. NextJS or Gatsby) the browser will download the static HTML, render it to the user and then React will try to hydrate.

Is there any way to tell, **outside of React** when React has hydrated?

I.e. if I wrote some javascript in the  of my static HTML, how could I determine when React has hydrated?